# Is UNNotificationServiceExtension guaranteed to call for every notification with mutable-content=1

Tags: ios

I understand that with silent notifications, there is a possibility of make n/w connections when app is in background. iOS may not always call `didReceiveNotification` depending on various conditions like connected to power etc.

I notice with iOS 10 we have `UNNotificationServiceExtension` which gets called before notification is delivered to user. In this extension we can actually make n/w connections in bg.

- If not, then what is the point of `UNNotificationServiceExtension`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the point of UNNotificationServiceExtension

For one thing — quite a big thing — it is to allow you to customize the interface that the user sees when force-touch-pressing / long-pressing the notification alert.